# how to obtain the post id in wordpress templates

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i know in wordpress loop

```
the_ID();
```

will output the post id,
if  i want to set $var = the post id;
what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the_ID(), which echoes its result, use the function get_the_ID(), which returns the ID and you can assing it to a variable to be used in your php script.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
/* do here what you need with $postid.. */
```

FYI, there's a nice official repository of WP APIs, the [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)